# Monitor goes into permanent sleep after boot up

Tags: 12.04, boot, graphics, monitor

My monitor goes into permanent sleep after boot up. The only thing that works is when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, it works but only as the terminal. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably either wrong resolution or wrong frequency rate. You may try executing this from the terminal you have access to:

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg